# Clicking on button using unique button label

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, dojo

I want to click on a button which has a label "Declaration":

```
<div class="LNTitleOuter">
    <div class="LNTitleInner" data-dojo-attach-point="navigationOptionTitle_pt">Declaration</div>
</div>
```

When I used the Selenium IDE to capture the click, then paste as Java code it returns:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.LNTitleOuter")).click();
```

Unfortunately, this is not unique. The only unique element is the description "Declaration".

How can I click this button using the "Declaration" reference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can locate the element *by xpath* checking it's text:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[. = 'Declaration']")).click();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
WebElement label = driver.findElement(By.className("LNTitleOuter")); 
String labeltxt = driver.findElement(By.className("LNTitleOuter")).getText();
if(labeltxt.equals("Declaration")){
    label.click();
}
```

can you try the above code.

Answer (score 0):

With Firefox Firebug detect your xpath element and execute:

```
String xpath = "/html/body/div[6]/div[2]/div/ul/li/address[1]/a";
WebElement we = driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath));
Thread.sleep(500);
we.click();
```

Comment: The problem with this is if the button moves somewhere else on the page the test will fail. As I said the only unique reference the **Declaration** text